# Very slow setState - React

Tags: reactjs

I'm rookie when it comes to react.
Bumped into problem when during handleDragEnd event in trello alike draggable board when wanted to put some logic:

```js
const openCloseDialog = () => {
    setOpenDialog(!openDialog);
}

const handleDragEnd = (cardId: number, sourceLaneId: number, targetLaneId: number, position: number, cardDetails: ICard): Boolean => {
    if (sourceLaneId != targetLaneId) {
        setDialogTitleContent(cardDetails.description)
        setCardId(cardId)
        setTargetLaneId(targetLaneId)
        openCloseDialog();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This bunch of simple setState causes huge performance issue.

Definition of states:

```js
const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [dialogTitleContent, setDialogTitleContent] = useState<string>("");
const [cardId, setCardId] = useState<number>(0);
const [targetLaneId, setTargetLaneId] = useState<number>(0);
```

When it comes to opening dialog then it's getting even worse.
Definition of Dialog component:

```
interface IProps {
    title: string,
    cardId: number,
    targetLaneId: number,
    openDialog: boolean,
    openCloseDialog: () => void,
    fetchCategories: () => void
}

export const DraggableDialog: FC<IProps> = ({
    title,
    cardId,
    targetLaneId,
    openDialog,
    openCloseDialog,
    fetchCategories
}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Dialog
                open={openDialog}
                onClose={() => openCloseDialog()}
                aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title">
                {`Do You want to move all payment records with following title?: "${title}"`}
                <Button onClick={moveOneCard} color="primary">
                    Just that one
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={moveManyCards} color="primary">
                    All of them
                </Button>
            </Dialog>
        </>
    );
}
```

Am I doing some obvious mistake which I'm not aware of?

Comment: I know it may be hard but it would be much clear if you can provide a `codesandbox` with the same functionality.

Comment: Did you try to use the React profiler to have a clearer picture of what is taking time?

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie it seems to me that it was more for a table component to cause the problem than the dialog itself. 
Here's profiler data: https://controlc.com/66842ea5